# Apps Script : Show dates -1 day if workday and different if it's week-end or bank holiday

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to manage product manufacturing dates.
Here is how the script works:

1. It modifies the format of the columns to be sure that they are dates (tab "Extraction")
2. It deletes the duplicates of this tab
3. He creates a new tab named "Dates" in which he pastes the dates of the tab "Extraction" (only the columns B and D).
4. He displays in column C the dates of column B - 1 day (if in B2 it is 20/05/2022, he copies in C2 the 19/05/2022).

I managed to write all these parts but I would like for step 4 to calculate according to the working days and bank holidays.

For example if the date in B2 is Monday 16 May 2022, I would like it to display in C2 Friday 13 May 2022. And if for example Friday May 13, 2022 is a bank holiday, I would like it to display Thursday May 12, 2022 in C2 instead.

So I created a tab listing all the bankholidays (same name) but I can't figure out how to write this part of the script.

What can I try next?

Here is the script:

```
function miseEnFormeDates() {
   // Déclaration des constantes et des variables
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("Extraction");
   var range = feuille.getRange('A:E');
   var tDates = []; var nbDates = 0; var tDonneesDateFab = []; var tDonneesDateDDM = [];

 // ----- RECOPIAGE DES DATES DANS UN OUVEL ONGLET ----- //
   // Format Date
   range.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
   // Suppression des doublons
   range.removeDuplicates().activate();
   // Ajout d'une nouvelle feuille nommée "Dates"
   yourNewSheet = classeur.insertSheet();
   yourNewSheet.setName("Dates");

   // Recopiage des dates de l'onglet "Extraction"" vers l'onglet "Dates"
   tDates = feuille.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
   nbDates = tDates.filter(String).length;
   const feuilleDates = classeur.getSheetByName("Dates");
   tDonneesDateFab = feuille.getRange("D2:D"+(nbDates+1)).getValues();
   tDonneesDateDDM = feuille.getRange("B2:B"+(nbDates+1)).getValues();
   feuilleDates.getRange("A1").setValue("Date fab.").setBackground("#33cccc").setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("white").setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
   feuilleDates.getRange("B1").setValue("DDM").setBackground("#33cccc").setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("white").setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');

   for (let i= 0; i < nbDates; i ++){
     feuilleDates.getRange("A"+(2+i)).setValue(tDonneesDateFab[i]).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
     feuilleDates.getRange("B"+(2+i)).setValue(tDonneesDateDDM[i]).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
   }

 // ----- AFFICHAGE DE DATE -1 ----- //
   feuilleDates.getRange("C1").setValue("Date -1").setBackground("#33cccc").setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("white").setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
   for (let i= 0; i < nbDates; i ++){
     var date = new Date(tDonneesDateDDM[i]);
     var result = new Date();
     var dateEnNombre =result.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
     dateFinale = new Date(dateEnNombre);
     feuilleDates.getRange("C"+(2+i)).setValue(dateFinale).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setVerticalAlignment('middle');
   }
 }
```

And here is [the link to the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13NWg_PamkslkSGiC0DX_8y7RQ-TGAlWwdK2kh049DnA/edit?usp=sharing) if you want to see how it looks like.

----- EDIT -----

I’ll try to explain better my problem and minimalize it.
I’ve a Sheets where i take dates and report them in an other tab of this same Sheets.

It’s work perfectly but now, i would like to have in a separate column the day before the dates who re reported.And if these dates reported are in week-end or a bank holiday, i would like the day before.

I’ll give you two exemples for be as understandable as possible.
My date is monday 23 may 2022, i would like to have wednesday 20 may 2022 reported.

And if wednesday 20 may 2022 is a bank holiday, i would like to have thursday 19 may 2022 reported in the next cell.

I have a tab with all of the bank holidays and, if it’s possible i would like ask all of them each time to know if the “day before” is a bank holiday

[image]

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Could you set the desired output on the sample sheet that you provided? It's still not that clear what you want to do with the dates.

Comment: I edited my code. Sorry for my late answer